# FOSS Intelligent Character Recognition (ICR)

Tags: .net, open-source, ocr, handwriting, icr

Does anyone know of an open source Intelligent Character Recognition (ICR) library? There seems to be plenty out there for OCR but I am focusing on recognizing handwriting and would love it if there was an open source solution out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OCRopus](http://code.google.com/p/ocropus/) claims to do handwriting recognition. It's available under the Apache License 2.0.

Comment: The FAQ states that OCRopus does not work for handwritten text and only for printed material. Check it here: http://code.google.com/p/ocropus/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions

Answer (score 6):

OCRopus does not appear to be ICR-ready at this time.  From an OCRopus developer forum message on Dec 18, 2009.

> Pretty much all thee old code for
>   handwriting recognition is there and
>   it's now accesssible from Python; it
>   should be fairly easy to script a
>   handwriting recognizer. However,
>   making it perform well will require a
>   lot of training and tweaks, plus
>   careful language modeling. Depending
>   on the nature of the handwritten
>   material, it may also be necessary to
>   integrate additional recognizers (HMM,
>   convolutional nnet).

I was looking for exactly the same as you.  However, that (and other similar comments) were enough to convince me that there would be a great deal of work required to get OCRopus ready for prime time ICR.  I could not in all conscience recommend it to my client right now.

Also, I see that there has not been a new release of OCRopus in over a year.  Hardly reassuring.