# Python OCR library or handwritten character recognition engine

Tags: python, ocr, image-recognition

Could you recommend some python libraries or source code for OCR and handwritten character recognition?

Comment: handwriting recognition (ICR) is actually quite hard, but OCROpus can do some: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730594/foss-intelligent-character-recognition-icr

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried [pytesser](http://code.google.com/p/pytesser/)?

Comment: 404 - link deserted.

Comment: this is only `Optical Character Recognition ` module not Handwriting Character Recognition library.