# Python handwriting recognition software?

Tags: python

Is there a Python handwriting recognition library?  What are the inputs to hand writing recognition packages, .jpg images?  .pdf images?

Comment: Did you see this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708779/python-ocr-library-or-handwritten-character-recognition-engine

Answer (score 2):

[Zinnia](http://zinnia.sourceforge.net/) is a C/C++ library with SWIG generated wrappers for Perl/Python/Ruby. It has a BSD license and converts user pen strokes provided as coordinates into character best matches. It also has a training module.

It looks like it performs single character recognition, so you might need to build something on top of it to improve the results.

[PenCommander](http://www.phatware.com/index.php?q=product/details/pencommander/overview) from [PhatWare](http://www.phatware.com) is a commercial, non-Python, Windows-only SDK. If you can live with all of those limitations, PhatWare products are the best handwriting recognition products that I've found so far, although I haven't been looking that hard since the Microsoft's digital ink for the Tablet PC came out. I'm still saving for the Tablet PC though :-(