# Reading text from an image

Tags: python

Is there a way we can read the alphabets from an image, some kind of text recognition method using python.

What I have to do is, read some images to get the text written on them.

Please suggest.

Comment: sounds like a decaptcha...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python OCR library or handwritten character recognition engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708779/python-ocr-library-or-handwritten-character-recognition-engine)

Comment: @Bolu: Right, because no one ever used OCR for any other reason.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See [OCROPUS](http://code.google.com/p/ocropus/)

**EDIT:**
Also after seeing the other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708779/python-ocr-library-or-handwritten-character-recognition-engine) (of which this question is a duplicate), [pytesser](http://code.google.com/p/pytesser/) is much simpler if your image only contains text and no noise (images/illustrations)