# Use a scanner device from Python

Tags: python, image-scanner

I am trying to use a scanner device from Python. I have looked into two libraries (pyscanner and imagescanner) that claim to solve this problem, but they don't. The first one, breaks while importing the module, the second one, I could not find the files.

I have also found some libraries in Java (JTwain) that can be used, but I would rather use Python.

I would really thank if someone can help me with this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708779/python-ocr-library-or-handwritten-character-recognition-engine

Comment: probably you mean pyscanning ? pyscanner is not related with scanner devices.

Comment: yeah, I misspoke, it is pyscanning