# recognizing letter in image OCR

Tags: c#, ocr, image-recognition

i searched with no result. If i copy other topic, please delete, not making mess.
I have question about image recognition OCR using C#

I am working on image which shows the scrabble. 
First i converted image to grayscale, thresholded to find out only black letters and then I used median to avoid the walls around letters.

Now, how to start to get at the end function which will recognize letter? Should i somehow now separate 'foreach' letters :-) or just start recognizing ? On what problem should i take attention before start recognizing? Any sources will be welcome. :-)

Any idea will be also very helpful.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011772/reading-character-from-image/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is a big, vast discussion...
If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, I suggest you use [Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/), an open source OCR in C++, or [Tessnet2](http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/) which is a .NET wrapper around it.

I had the same approach as yours, i.e. grayscale then thresholds etc in .NET, then I adapted a bit Tesseract (Tessnet2 is a wrapper around Tesseract 2.0, not 3.x which is the actual version) to have a good interface for OCR output then I have good results.

Here is [another subject on OCR and Tesseract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908919/tesseract-ocr-library-learning-font/4931336#4931336) on Stack Overflow which describes more precisely what it consists in.

Of course if what you want is play with OCR concepts to make them work by yourself, this is not the good way :-)

Comment: i would like make myself it it is possible, can you give me any good direction or links? I searched in google for it whole day but i think i am too old or i search somehow wrong because i got not interesting results, none of any alghoritms ;( or ideas how to start/do (it doenst have to be for c#)